# UIImage initialization options

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

When should someone use  UIImage's method `init(contentsOfFile:)`, when is appropriate to use `init(named:)` and when `init(data:)`? I read about it and it seems the only difference is that with `init(named:)` image stays around for a while and with `init(contentsOfFile:)` is it deallocated as soon as possible eg when it is not on screen anymore. Please correct my assumptions if they are wrong. Not sure what `init(data:)` is good for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you use `init(contentsOfFile:)` when you for example have a path to an image stored somewhere on your phone.

you use `init(named:)` when you have an image with the passed name in your application bundle.

and you use `init(data:)` when you have some image data (for example you downloaded the image data from some web source) and want to create the image from that data.

**one important difference between the three initializers is that only the `imageNamed` initializer caches the returned image object!**

you should really consult the official documentation for questions like this though: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006890-CH3-SW11

Comment: I think that I can specify path to app bundle. So it is like a shortcut method?

Comment: kind of. there is an important difference though: `initWithContentsOfFile` does not cache the image object. `imageNamed` does.

Comment: so use contentsOfFile for big images and the one that wont be used frequently, right?

Comment: as the documentation states: `If you have an image file that will only be displayed once and wish to ensure that it does not get added to the system’s cache, you should instead create your image using imageWithContentsOfFile:. This will keep your single-use image out of the system image cache, potentially improving the memory use characteristics of your app.`